# Is this question really too broad?

Tags: discussion, scope

It has been asserted that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32038883/are-linux-programs-as-portable-as-windows-programs) must be out of scope for SO because it is a "list question", apparently on the basis that it includes a plural: specifically, the summary question is "What are the limitations to creating portable software [...] ?"  *Edit: the discussion in question has now been deleted.  Remainder of my commentary on that aspect removed.*

This seems to me to be an important question.  Is it really too broad?  It has been answered, so it is clear that answers would not need to be too long for SO; and there were only two (relevant) answers posted which suggests that it would not necessarily attract too many answers.

Thoughts?

Comment: Too broad means, there are too many possible answers, not that the question isn't answerable.

Comment: What @πάνταῥεῖ said. The question appears to be "Too broad": _"There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs."_

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: the answer is either yes, it can be done, and this is how, or no, it can't, and this is why.  I don't see how there can be too many possible answers.

Comment: Are you sure? "What are the limitations" doesn't sound like a yes/no question to me.

Comment: Questions that can be answered with a simple "yes" or "no" tend not to be too useful ... (think of "Can I do x?" – the answer is 'well apparently you cannot'). IMO the question *is* on topic, can be definitely answered, is not open to opinionated answers, and does not ask for a "list". Those limitations are well-defined and so they can be *enumerated* – it's nothing like a "list of books" or "list of ideas".

Comment: @HarryJohnston As long as "I have no clue about the subject in question. But I came here to downvote/closevote because I saw a link on Meta" (aka "Meta effect") people don't flood in there, that question will survive. It's simply asking about the level of binary compatibility supported by Linux which *is* a valuable one and an important piece of information for Linux programmers, at least.

Comment: @BlueMoon: Obviously I agree with you that it is a valuable question, and I'm pleased that (as a subject matter expert, which I'm not) you agree with me, but it had already been closed *twice* even before I brought it to Meta's attention (and then once again afterwards, before it got locked).

Comment: @BoltClock: just poor phrasing, IMO.  A list of reasons why something is impossible isn't useful to anyone, so it seemed more reasonable to take the question as a whole and interpret it as either "how can I do this" or "can I do this".  Note also that the "What are the limitations" bit was only in the summary, the question in the main part of the post was "Can I do that in Linux too?"

Comment: @BlueMoon: perhaps you could comment on Matt's answer?  (And thanks for fixing the typo, BTW.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston I don't think the question is too broad (the very first re-open vote when it was closed the first time was mine :). Even if the question left open for 5 years I bet it wouldn't receive 10 answers. One justification is that it generates a lot noise to due to repeated opening/closing and it would be consuming task for a mod.  But when a moderator closes (even for completely the wrong reasons), there's very little anyone could do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In it's original form, the question was too broad.

1. When an OP feels a need to *summarise* a question at the bottom of their question, it *screams* that it is too broad, or vague, or big.
2. > What are the limitations to creating portable software on linux, as people do on Windows?

   There are possibly (and undoubtedly) many. This again, makes the question too broad.

---

The question was then edited with an update. However, that edit invalidated the existing answers the question accrued (as they attempt to answer the much vaguer question), which is why I've now rolled back that edit.

The edit proposed a new question:

> How can I compile my software in a way where I guarantee that it'll work on all these systems for as longer time as possible?

Now, given I'm not an expert in the field at hand, I'm not sure how many answers there are to this question. My concern is that there are many, and everyone will use (and propose) different techniques for how they compile their code so it lasts as long as *they* need it to. If my concerns are valid, then this is another question that is inappropriate for Stack Overflow. If my concerns are **wrong**, then go ahead and ask it as a new question.

---

<sup>Why am I posting this here? Because I locked the original question, so if I was to post a summarised version of this as a comment to explain my actions, no-one would be able to reply to it, hence me posting an answer here, so people can.</sup>

Comment: Hmmm.  The post asks two questions (or, depending on your point of view, the same question twice) and I'm worried that I've misled you by focusing on the objectionable version rather than the other one.  I think the key phrase - from the original post, not the amended one - was "Can I do that in linux too?"  So I think the edit clarified and rephrased the question but did not fundamentally change it.

Comment: Also, I don't think the rephrasing from "can I do this" to "how can I do this" invalidated the existing answers;  amon's answer is still good, in particular "individual distributions might provide stronger compatibility guarantees", and Nazar554's answer is still OK because "you can't and this is why" is always a valid answer to "how can I do this".  (The third answer was wrong to begin with.)

Comment: Perhaps, OP felt the need to *summarise* because of close/downvotes? I don't think it's necessarily an admission of guilt. "There are possibly (and undoubtedly) many." -- This assertion seems to be solely based on the word "limitations". OP could easily rephrase the question to remove the "offending" words. To me whether something is "too broad" or not depends on the possible answer(s) on the subject rather than based on certain words in the question.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: In it's original form, the question contains the following questions: *Are Linux programs as portable as Windows programs?*. *Can I do that [run the same software on two computers] in linux two?* and *What are the limitations to creating portable software on linux, as people do on Windows?*. It's ***simply*** too vague and broad. The edit then added a 4th question *How can I compile my software in a way where I guarantee that it'll work on all these systems for as longer time as possible?*. As I said in my answer, that *by itself* is *possibly* a suitable question.

Comment: @BlueMoon: I didn't mean to imply that *just* because the question has a summary, it is too-broad. I meant that it is a good indicator that the question is too broad. I'm not disputing that rephrasing the question could make it on-topic (as I alluded to myself in my answer above), nor am I disputing that the (amount) of possible answers makes a question too broad; that is why it is up to the OP (per the close reason) to *add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs*.

Comment: OK, I guess things will have to rest here.  I'd have preferred to see a subject matter expert fix the question, or failing that post a new one (I know I wouldn't dare if I were the OP!) but no doubt the subject will come up again sooner or later.  Perhaps we'll have better luck next time. :-)